# Using a regression coefficient as independent variable

Tags: regression-coefficients, measurement-error, two-step-estimation

Two continuous variables, $Z$ and $X$, are measured at 60 time points during a week for a given person. At the end of the week, the persons value of a variable $Y$ is measured. This is repeated during six consecutive weeks. For each weeks data the regression coefficient $\beta_1$ is estimated in linear model

$$Z = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$$

At the end of the six weeks, for a given observed person there are six $\beta_1$ values and six $Y$ values. There are about 100 persons in the study. The final goal is to investigate how $\beta_1$ influences the dependent variable $Y$ in regression model:

$$Y = b_0 + b_1\beta_1 + \varepsilon$$

In this final equation the independent variable is $\beta_1$, which is an estimate based on 60 observations and this causes a problem, because $\beta_1$ has, say, "measurement error". What kind of model could I use to deal with this problem?

Comment: A mixed effects repeated measures model should allow you to estimate variation in the *effect* of $X$ on $Y$ by adding at least one error term for $\beta$ at the level of time (you might also add one at the level of individual). If your data are structured as times of measurement nested within individuals, maybe you will need to use an IGLS estimator (unless you want to go fully Bayesian).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $i$ indexes individuals, and $t$ indexes times of measures within individuals:

$$\begin{align*}Y_{ti} & = \beta_{0,ti} + \beta_{1,t}X_{ti} + \epsilon_{0,ti} + \epsilon_{1,ti}X_{ti} + \mu_{0,i}\\\\
\text{where, for example}\\\\
\left[\begin{array}$\epsilon_{0}\\\epsilon_{1}\end{array}\right]&\sim \Omega\left[0,\begin{array}{llr}\sigma^2_{\epsilon0}\\\sigma_{\epsilon 01} & \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon2}\end{array}\right]\text{, and }\sigma^2_{\mu}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{\mu})\end{align*}$$

You will also need to make choices about how you want to estimate the variance/covariance matrix for $\epsilon_{0,ti}$ and $\epsilon_{1,ti}X_{ti}$ (e.g., constrain covariance $\sigma_{\epsilon 01}$ to zero and assume independent variances $\sigma^2_{\epsilon 0}$ & $\sigma^2_{\epsilon 1}$, constrain covariance to zero and assume equal variances, estimate covariance without constraints, etc.). MLwiN can estimate this kind of model using IGLS or a Bayesian MCMC model (as can BUGS, JAGS, etc. for the latter).

The term $\beta_{1,ti}$ estimates the *average effect* of $X$ on $Y$ across all times.

The terms $\sigma^2_{\epsilon 1}$, and if constrained or estimated to be zero, the terms $\sigma^2_{\epsilon 0}$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon 01}$ are combined in a quadratic function of $X_{ti}$ to model variation in $\beta_1$ across values of $X_{ti}$ (i.e. this is a model of complex variance of the effect of $X$ give your repeated measures structure).

My answer is making assumptions about the sufficiency of your sample size, the particulars of your study design (e.g., does $t=1$ or $t=24$ mean the same thing for all individuals?), normal or multivariate normal errors, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for your answer. However, I think my problem is different because the independent is not simply a variable but a regression coefficient. It is as if a lower-level result (X -> Z) influences the higher-level outcome (Y). Maybe this is possible with multilevel modelling too, but I'm not sure. If I found a way to analyse this I will mention it here. Best regards, Ben.

Comment: Hi @BenP mixed models, such as what I describe do precisely what you want: estimate variation in slopes/$\beta$s (that's more or less the $\beta$ as independent variable part). See for example Figure 1 in Duncan, C., Jones, K., & Moon, G. (1998). Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research. *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1), 97–117.

Comment: Hi Alexis, the problem I have is that the independent variable, your X_ti variable, is not an observed variable, but an aggregated measure (which was estimated before by some regression model). It's influence (b_1 in my second equation) on the dependent Y is not random but simply fixed.

Comment: What I could do is simply use this aggregated measure as a predictor in my final model, but then I'm ignoring the fact that this "X" variable has uncertainty (a std. error). As result, the b_1 coefficient may suffer of attenuation.

Comment: In SEM one could correct for this. My final analysis of the six values of Y and X (= aggregated measure) per person will use random effects for person and time with whatever covariance matrix fits well, using e.g. lmer or lme in R. That is not a problem. But accounting for the uncertainty in the independent definitely is, and I do not know how to do that yet. Maybe mplus has this possibility or lavaan in R. Best regards, Ben.